# get file path from dialogresult

Tags: c#, string, directory

```
FolderBrowserDialog fd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
strPassKey = tea.Decrypt(strPassKey, "HPPower");
DialogResult result = fd.ShowDialog();
if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{                              
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(fd.SelectedPath);  // fd.SelectedPath contains the path of folder with files
    foreach (var xfile in Directory.GetFiles(fd.SelectedPath, "*.xml"))
    {
        xWorkloadDoc.Load(xfile);
        foreach (var decryptfile in Directory.GetFiles(fd.SelectedPath, "*.xml")) 
        {
            string foldrpth = xfile.Replace(decryptfile, "");  // string gives null
        }

    }
}
```

`fd.SelectedPath` contains the path of the file in folder. Can we get this path  in the string `foldrpth`?

Comment: Your code is pretty flawed - maybe you should fix some of the errors first. For example, you iterate all the files in the folder and store the result in `files`, but you never use this? Then you iterate in a nested loop over all the files *again* (twice)? What is that code supposed to do anyway?

Comment: `GetFiles` already returns an array that contains the full path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like

```
System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(....)
```

[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)